# How to Number Each Group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I use a window function or similar, to number each group or partition of rows, based on certain shared characteristics?

**For example:**

I have a list of names ordered alphabetically that I wish to group and identify using IDs that describe the group that they belong to and position within each group.

```
-------------------------------------------
| outer_id | inner_id | src_id |   name   |
|----------|----------|--------|----------|
|     1    |     1    |  88129 | albert   |
|     1    |     2    |  88130 | albrecht |
|     1    |     3    |  88131 | allan    |
|     2    |     1    |  88132 | barnaby  |
|     2    |     2    |  88133 | barry    |
|     2    |     3    |  88134 | bart     |
-------------------------------------------
```

I can achieve `inner_id`, `src_id` and `name` using a query similar to the following:

```
WITH cte (src_id, name) AS (

    VALUES

    (88129, 'albert'),
    (88130, 'albrecht'),
    (88131, 'allan'),
    (88132, 'barnaby'),
    (88133, 'barry'),
    (88134, 'bart')

)

SELECT row_number() OVER (partition by left(name, 1) ORDER BY name DESC) AS inner_id, src_id, name
FROM cte;
```

How would I go about adding an `outer_id` column as shown, to represent each window (or group)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by left(name, 1)) as outer_id,
       row_number() over (partition by left(name, 1) order by name desc) as inner_id,
       src_id, name
from cte;
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you Gordon, and also for the example.